# backports reversed debian

Tags: debian

How can I install a package from Debian Jessie in Stretch?

Note I'm on Stretch and I want to install a package from Jessie, because I'm running an architecture that's only supported by it and missing in Stretch

Comment: I've re-read this a few times and your wording is confusing.  Could you [edit](https://unix.stackexchange.com/posts/499450/edit) your question to be in the form:   I have an <architecture> system running <release> installed on my system.  I want to install a package from <other release>.  Note: this <package or release> is not supported on <architecture> in <release>

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can add the Jessie repositories, by duplicating the Stretch lines in `/etc/apt/sources.list` and replacing `stretch` by `jessie` in one of each pair. You’ll end up with something like

```
deb http://ftp.debian.org/debian jessie main
deb http://ftp.debian.org/debian stretch main

deb http://ftp.debian.org/debian jessie-updates main
deb http://ftp.debian.org/debian stretch-updates main

deb http://security.debian.org jessie/updates main
deb http://security.debian.org stretch/updates main
```

Then run `apt update`, and you’ll be able to install Jessie packages (as long as nothing in your installed packages prevents it).

Note that Jessie is now in its LTS phase, so security updates are only provided on `amd64`, `i386`, `armel` and `armhf`. See [the Debian wiki](https://wiki.debian.org/LTS) for details.